# Query posts from multiple post types sorted by overarching menu order

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, menu-order

I have three different post types named `activity`, `publication` and `project`.

I want all posts from these three post types to appear on one page on my website ordered by an overarching menu position.

Therefore, the first step was to merge all the posts of these post types on same admin screen. Here my code to achieve that:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'join_cpt_list_wspe_113808' );

function join_cpt_list_wspe_113808( $query ) {
    // If not backend, bail out
    if( !is_admin() )
        return $query;

    // Detect current page and list of CPTs to be shown in Dashboard > Posts > Edit screen
    global $pagenow;
    $cpts = array( 'activity', 'publication', 'project' );

    if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'post' == get_query_var('post_type') ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', $cpts );

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'add_cpt_column_wspe_113808' );

foreach( array( 'activity', 'publication', 'project' ) as $cpt )
    add_action( "manage_{$cpt}_posts_custom_column", 'show_cpt_column_wspe_113808', 10, 2 );

function add_cpt_column_wspe_113808( $columns ) {
    $columns[ 'cpt' ] = 'Post Type';
    return $columns;
}

function show_cpt_column_wspe_113808( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'cpt' != $column_name )
        return;
    echo get_post_type( $post_id );
}
```

And now I need your help:

I’d like the posts in this »dashboard view« to be sorted by their menu position, which shall operate independent from the `menu_order` parameter on the individual post type pages. So I probably need a custom parameter like `overarching_menu_order`.

My goal is to output all the posts with a custom query like the one below ordered by this custom parameter:

```
$args = array(
  "post_type"      => array("activity", "author", "project"), 
  "posts_per_page" => -1,
  "orderby"        => "meta_value",
  "meta_key"       => "overarching_menu_order",
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `menu_order`? It is after all exactly what it is designed for... But regardless, can you not just set you required parameters using the `$query->set()` method in the same way as you did for your `post_type` array?

Comment: And thinking about it... each to there own, but if you are merging all three custom post types, why not just use the `post` post type and create categories?  As I say, each to their own, but it would help me (and I suspect others) to help you if I understood your reasoning.

Comment: Because `menu_order` shall work with the individual post type pages and shall not be affected by the order on the page where all post of the three post types are displayed.

Comment: I have three different post types because each post type has its specific metaboxes which would not be possible if they all would be part of the same post type.

Comment: Ok, fair enough on the post types.  For `menu_order`, it is possible to add a secondary `orderby` parameter, such as `post_type` - so if all 3 types add the order `10` you could still control wich of those is displayed first.  If that's no good, what exactly is the problem? You've identifed that you can add `overarching_menu_order` as a custom value, and you know how to manipulate the query using the `pre_get_posts` hook and the `$query->set()` method...

Comment: Yep, you’re certainly right … It already works with my custom meta key `overarching_menu_order`. My problem is that I’d like it to be sorted via drag’n’drop (like with the Simple Custom Post Order Plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/simple-custom-post-order). But that’ll be another question. Thanks for your help!